# Checking or unchecking a checkbox based on value in a group with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am really new to Javascript and know absolutely nothing about JQuery, so I apologize now for my newbie status.

I have an array of checkboxes (up to 18) that have the same name and class (can't change that fact):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="elective_id[]" value="112" class="elective_id">
<input type="checkbox" name="elective_id[]" value="128" class="elective_id">
<input type="checkbox" name="elective_id[]" value="135" class="elective_id">
<input type="checkbox" name="elective_id[]" value="322" class="elective_id" onClick="checkSister(322);">
<input type="checkbox" name="elective_id[]" value="323" class="elective_id" onClick="checkSister(323);">
```

Within that array will be 3 pairs of checkboxes that need their counterpart checked/unchecked when their pair is checked/unchecked. The three pairs are 320,321 & 322,323 & 345,346.

If checkbox with value 322 was selected, how can I automatically select the pair?

```
function checkSister(brother) {
 if (brother=="322") {
  document.getElementById("322").checked = true;        
  document.getElementById("323").checked = true;
 } else if (brother=="322") {
  document.getElementById("322").checked = true;        
  document.getElementById("323").checked = true;
 }
}
```

I know that is not right, but haven't figured out how to get the right variable selected, let alone deselected.

Any help you can provide would greatly be appreciated,
Jim

Comment: Your checkboxes are missing the `id` attribute that you're selecting.

Comment: So if I added id="323" to the checkbox it would work?

Comment: I have added the id number and still doesn't work.

Comment: OK, got it working as I forgot to close the script. Only problem is now I cannot get the pairs to deselect. Here is the code:   
`function checkSister(brother) {
if (brother=="322") {
       if (document.getElementById("322").checked = true) {

        document.getElementById("322").checked = false;

        document.getElementById("323").checked = false;

       } else {

     document.getElementById("322").checked = true;        

     document.getElementById("323").checked = true;
    }`

Comment: Figured it out using ideas from everybody. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily without jquery using [querySelectorAll](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'][value='112']")[0].checked=true;
```

or you can query by name and value like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='elective_id[]'][value='112']")[0].checked=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert that vanilla JavaScript to jQuery,

```
function checkSister(brother) {
    if (brother=="322") {
      $("#322").prop("checked") = true;        
      $("#323").prop("checked") = true;  
 } else if (brother=="322") {
      $("#322").prop("checked") = true;     
      $("#323").prop("checked") = true;  
     }
}
```